# Scala: Finding unique value in a list of tuples

Tags: string, scala, set, tuples, operation

I have a list of tuples in Scala:

```
("BLUE", 2, 4)
("RED", 2, 29)
("GREEN", 29, 0)
("RED", 18, 2)
```

This list is quite long. I'm looking for an efficient list operation that would give me a list of unique colors (the first string in the tuple). In other words, I'm looking for this:

```
List("RED", "BLUE", "GREEN")
```

Order doesn't really matter to me. I know that this can be accomplished iteratively, but I'm looking to learn functional programming and I'm not sure how to do this with an operation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

`tupleList.map(_._1).distinct`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a long `List`, as you say, then you'll want to traverse it only once.

```
tups.foldLeft(Set[String]())(_+_._1).toList
```

Comment: This solution is evidently better than  `map/distinct` when the list is big.